# Joining Club Nintendo without a PIN

Tags: nintendo-wii, nintendo-ds, club-nintendo

I´ve just bought a second-hand Nintendo Wii console, and I have previously bought a second-hand Nintendo DSXL. I´m trying to register for Club Nintendo, but it asks me to enter a PIN number which I did not receive with my second-hand consoles.

On the US Club Nintendo website it appears that you can use your console´s Serial Number to join the club, but here in the UK there is no such statement.

Is it possible to join Club Nintendo without a PIN from a brand new piece of Nintendo hardware/software?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to join the club without any hardware information, just an e-mail address. You just can't register hardware without the registration codes for that hardware and if someone already registered it, you can't re-register it. You're best bet is to call [Nintendo support](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/index.jsp) and let them know you have purchased a used system so they can associate it with your Club account, and they can hash out any confusion when you talk to them.

Since this question was posted it has come to light that Nintendo is shutting down the Club program internationally. The US and UK received notice on January 20th, 2015. Asia was given notice a few months prior.

Comment: As stated in the original question, there is no such option on the UK website, and it appears you need a serial number to join. Ah well.

Comment: I just looked at the site, what about this "Alternatively, if you don't have a product with a product registration card (for example, Wii U hardware), you can enter your Nintendo Network ID instead for a temporary membership: Use Nintendo Network ID" ...
https://www.nintendo.co.uk/NOE/en_GB/club_nintendo/join_the_club/index_register-0b-productcode.jsp

Comment: You only get Nintendo Network IDs with Wii Us, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Last comment... well, it's probably all moot anyways. We just found out the Club program is being canceled in the U.S. and it was already cancelled in Japan. I imagine the Europe will be getting a similar notice soon.

Comment: Annd... yeah, it's official. No more UK program either: http://www.nintendo.co.uk/News/2015/January/Important-information-about-the-discontinuation-of-Club-Nintendo-949921.html?utm_medium=Nintendo+of+Europe

Comment: Inconceivable!!